# XML Schema: Ignore tags with foreign namespace

Tags: xsd

Say I have the following xml document:

```xml
<root xmlns:p="uri:myNamespace">
  <p:tagA>
    <p:tagB />
  </p:tagA>
</root>
```

The tagB must only be inside a tagA. I can write an xsd that validates that:

```xml
<xsd:schema ... targetNamespace="uri:myNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="tagA">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="tagB" type="..." />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Now here comes the problem: I want to ignore any tags in between of foreign namespace:

```xml
<root xmlns:p="uri:myNamespace">
  <p:tagA>
    <whatever />
    <foo>
      <bar>
        <p:tagB />
      </bar>
    </foo>
  </p:tagA>
</root>
```

As you can see tagB is now nested within other tags without namespace.

Is it possible (how?) to write an XSD that still enforces that the only tag within `tagA` from my namespace is a `tagB` but there may be any tags of other namespaces inbetween?

Answer (score 0):

The content models used in XSD (and DTDs, and Relax NG) to constrain the content of an element define legal sequences of children; they work like a single production rule in a context-free grammar.  It's possible to constrain descendants at deeper levels, but it requires an unbroken chain of declarations:  in your example you need declarations for `foo` and `bar` when they appear within a `p:tagA` element, to ensure that between them they contain exactly one `p:tagB` element.  But your starting point is that you don't want to constrain those elements.

So:  you cannot use content models to express the constraint you have in mind.

In XSD 1.1, you can use an assertion attached to the `p:tagA` element to require that it contain exactly on `p:tagB` element among its descendants (`count(.//p:tagB) eq 1`).  You cannot, however, use an assertion attached to `p:tagB` to require that it appear only in `p:tagA` elements:  assertions can look down, but not up, in the tree.  (If you know the name of a container guaranteed to be present, you can use an assertion on that container that asserts that every p:tagB element is contained by a p:tagA element, using an assertion like `count(.//p:tagA//p:tagB) eq count(.//p:tagB)`.)

XSD 1.1 is currently supported by some but not all XSD validators.